# Maximum number of threads supported by JMeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I want to do load test with 10000 users using JMeter. I want to know whether my system is capable of doing that.

My System Configuration :

RAM: 4 GB

Processor : Intel core 2 quad 2.50 GHz

OS: windows 7 (64 bit)

please let me know if it is not possible suggest me the alternative

Comment: See this if you want to scale as never before :https://medium.com/@nirmalmewada/unveiling-the-secret-achieving-50k-concurrent-user-load-using-jmeter-with-2-5g-ram-only-51f892b233ce

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This greatly depends on the system you are running jMeter on and how heavy the test is. Your system does not look heavy enough for 10k concurrent users, from the jMeter documentation I get the feeling 1k is the target limit for each machine.

Have a look at http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html for running your tests from multiple remote jMeter nodes.

> In the event that your JMeter client machine is unable,
>   performance-wise, to simulate enough users to stress your server or is
>   limited at network level, an option exists to control multiple, remote
>   JMeter engines from a single JMeter client. By running JMeter
>   remotely, you can replicate a test across many low-end computers and
>   thus simulate a larger load on the server. One instance of the JMeter
>   client can control any number of remote JMeter instances, and collect
>   all the data from them. This offers the following features:
>
> Saving of test samples to the local machine Managment of multiple
>   JMeterEngines from a single machine No need to copy the test plan to
>   each server - the client sends it to all the servers

Maybe you can use your colleague's desktops in the evening and or in the weekend.

Or try running the remote nodes in the cloud, this might be very cost effective for large loads as you only pay for the machines as you use them, beats buying more and or better desktops/servers to load test from. See: http://www.http503.com/2012/run-jmeter-on-amazon-ec2-cloud/

Comment: Increasing JMeter heap size (e.g. allowing JMeter to use 2 GB of your RAM, as by default this value is very low) will also helps in handling more load and running heavy scripts with listeners, without this your JMeter too gets hang and throws memory exception. https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterFAQ#JMeter_keeps_getting_.22Out_of_Memory.22_errors.__What_can_I_do.3F    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286750/jmeter-outofmemoryerror

Comment: I tested how many users I could get per core and it's about 500 (test on Windows and Mac). So I could get about 2k users per machine. You'll need to spread out the load as this answer points out.

Comment: @Niels, [Where do you](http://xkcd.com/285)  get the "feeling 1k is the target limit"?

Comment: From running load tests on my systems with similar specs. Maybe faster machines can handle more. But you have threads, memory, io and tcp/ip bottlenecks on a system. To find out what those limits are try to push the limit on your system. Make small working test and scale it up until it starts failing..while you know the server sided limit ofcourse :) but I have also run into DDOS protections on some networks ;-)

Answer (score 4):

'10000 users' using jmeter is pretty tough on single machine considering given configuration, the maximum number of threads supported by jmeter will be 300 to 400 depending on your script, eventually jmeter will get stuck with 'OutOfMemoryError' and it will create a very large dump file. it would be best to use [distributed jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf) and simulate distributed '10000 users' for creating load.

Comment: But using this Distributed method, you will require lots machine for generating your required load (on an rough estimate 20 slaves and a master machine).

Answer (score 0):

This is depends on how you design your test case. I have tested 500-8000 concurrent user per host depends on host power.

Here is a screenshot from my 24T/32GB Host testing for 8000RPS and still more capable. 
https://github.com/sarkershantonu/Bug-Storing-WS/blob/master/README.md#test-results

in aws, i used to test 500 concurrent users for 7.5GB/4Core Xeon aws.

Now, you need to optimize your test case and run in cli mode. 
Use minimum requests, memory, single listener (i save jtl to analysis but add summerizer for looking test while running)

You can see tips & tricks from my blog also https://shantonusarker.blogspot.com/p/jmeter.html